# How do I slim down JBOSS?

Tags: java, jboss

We're using Jboss, but we are really only using its JMS stuff. So, is there a way that I can trim down what's loaded when Jboss starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 6 years ago, [here's a blog entry](http://www.murraywilliams.com/computers/buildjboss/index.html) about configuring JBoss with "just the right stuff."

I haven't used JBoss in a few years, but in v4.0, you could just drop the desired jar files into the deployment directory, and JBoss would load... only those jars.

Comment: That's a great post and looks like just what I need. BUT, it stops before he explains how to add JMS! Perhaps I can glean what I need from it. I remember someone telling me that you could just drop the jars and I'll try that on Monday to see if that's all I need to do. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you drop the necessary jars, and only those that are necessary, into the "deploy" directory of the server you're running.

Comment: I guess the next question is this: which jars are the necessary ones? Can you point me to some docs on that? Seems like there should be some table somewhere with that info in it.

Comment: JBoss docs give a description of all the jars/rars/sars.  See http://docs.jboss.com/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html_single/#config-files, Chapter 4.

Answer (score 4):

You can go for a servlet container ([Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)) + a JMS provider (ex. [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)), without using an application server at all.

Comment: True, but not an answer to the question!  He could also use Windows Server, ASPNET, and MSMQ, but that is also not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Cheeso well, I diagree. The idea is that he will be able to run his current code on tomcat+jms. And won't be on msmq and aspnet

Comment: Its a pretty valid answer really. JBoss'es USP is that it is a complete full featured J2EE server out of the box. Tomcat is a lean mean servlet container, Geronimo may also be worth a look.

Comment: To be accurate, it is not an answer to the question. He asked "how to trim down JBoss?" The proposed answer explained that he could run something other than JBoss. That's not an answer to the question. It may be a valid approach but it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I agree this is a better solution than to try and put JBoss on a Diet. You will be much happier with the shorter startup times ;)

Comment: @Cheeso - if someone asks "how do I parse html with regex", all the answers are "you must not use regex, use a parser". So it does answer the question ;)

Comment: I appreciate the information and alternatives. Unfortunately, we're locked into Jboss. Sigh.

Comment: @Dopyiii - how and why are you locked?

Comment: Locked in by customer network limitation. Now, we're also locked in by time. We just don't have time to flush out another solution.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this, is making a separate profile on your JBoss server that contains only the things needed to use JMS. JBoss v5 comes standard with several profiles: minimal, default, standard, all and web. Each of those starts other services. If you do not specify any profile, you're using the "default" profile.

You can create your own profile starting from a copy of the minimal profile and adding services as needed for JMS support.

The JBoss documentation contains a bit of information on what the files in those profile directories are used for. See [Jboss server configurations](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html_single/index.html#The_JBoss_Server___A_Quick_Tour-Server_Configuration).

You didn't specify which version of JBoss that you are using. Keep in mind that there are some changes in the configuration between JBoss v4 and JBoss v5/6. The referenced documentation in the answer from Cheeso points to JBoss v4.

Comment: Good point: JBoss 5. I'd like to take the minimal configuration, but I simply don't know how to add the JMS service. Pardon my ignorance, but I'm inheriting this problem from someone else and absolutely no one here knows JBoss well enough to do a custom configuration.